# Proffile Layout: Table and / or CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a profile page.  The code is as follows:

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="pull-left" style="margin: 0 0 20px 20px;">
          <img src="{% if user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url %} {{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url }}" {% else %} {% avatar_url user 200 %}" alt="{{ user.get_full_name }}" {% endif %} width="100" height="100"/>
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-info" style="text-align: center;width:100%;display: flex;" role="alert">
            <span style="font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle; padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;float: left;margin: auto 0 auto auto;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign alert-info" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span style="font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle;text-align: initial;margin: auto auto auto 0;" class="alert-info" role="info">                  Your profile picture (left) is used to identify you here on str8RED.com.
              To change it,
              please upload an image at least 200x200 pixels in size.  Larger images
              will be resized.  Non-square images will be centred and cropped.</span>
          </div>
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'avatar_add' %}" role="form" class="form-inline text-center">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group space-above">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    Image Selection&hellip; <input id="id_avatar" name="avatar" type="file">
                  </span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          {% if upload_avatar_form.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin: 20px 0 0 0;">
              {% for error in upload_avatar_form.avatar.errors %}
                {{ error }}<br/>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
```

The outcome of the above code looks like:
[image]

What I would like to do is have the blue box sitting nicely to the left of the profile picture (currently a red  outline of a person) with the image selection still sat below it.  I have tried to use the grid from bootstrap without success.  I then thought about using tables but was unsure if that was the correct way forward.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add class pull-left to the div with the text. Than change position with the div that contains the image.

Comment: After trying that the info box comes first and then the image sits below it.  :/

Comment: I notice the width of the text box is set to 100%. You need to decrease that until the image appears on the same line. Probably 70% or 80% will do.

Comment: I set this to 75% which allowed it to work.  However, this then depends on the screen size and does not full truly responsive.

Comment: It will use 75% of the available screen size.

Comment: But if the screen size is small, say an iPhone 4 then I would want it to be 100% with the profile picture below.

Comment: Ok. Than you have to use media queries. I'll provide one in an answer. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media query with Bootstrap. Add this to your CSS file.

```
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  .alert.alert-info {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  .alert.alert-info {
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

Remove the width specification in the HTML.

Comment: Many thanks, It just does not seem right.  It feels like it should be done within the bootstrap grid.  I sadly need to go out but I will try this upon my return.